# Get PDF as file object in JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf, pdf-generation

Our app has a feature that allows you to print a web page with `window.print`. The print view has specific print styles. But I need to get this rendered PDF as a JS file object that I can manipulate later (send to another API). And I want to eliminate the print preview dialog.

So the desired scenario is

1. User clicks a button (print)
2. There is no print window
3. I get a rendered version of the window as a JS pdf file object that I can manipulate on with preserved styling (identical to the window.print file)

I'm open to the new libraries. The app is on React.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't really clear. When I say button, I mean an HTML button tag.

Comment: I just need a pdf file  from HTML, can't I really have it? I tested the https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-pdf-js but it looks like shit. And the window.print is the best result. I want to get a pdf exactly as is.

Comment: @KJ Thanks mate. That's done a thing for me. However, that was part of a bigger task. We need to export HTML to DOCX. And what I've been doing is HTML -> PDF -> DOCX . I tested the converter services for PDF -> DOCX and the results were poor for such complex-styled document that we have + no control to fix that.  The source of the truth is HTML so using docx.js is not cool because converting CSS styles to a format that the lib understands is so possible but hard. HTML to docx export functions show poor results too. Do you have any ideas about that how to make that conversion in other ways?

Comment: html -> word -> pdf. Okay. Any libs / frameworks / approaches that you would recommend to use for HTML -> word and word -> pdf conversions? thanks